# How can I remove and replace content in a HTML tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I need to change the content of a link, but I can only change the CSS of the page I'm working on. I tried using the `content` property in `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. But I didn't find a way to replace the value with the new one. I was able only to append the content to the value specified between tags, at the beginning and at the end, instead of completely replacing it like I need.

```css
a:before {
  content: 'ciao 1'
}

a:after {
  content: 'ciao 2'
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/">CSS Tutorial</a>
```

What can I do to actually "replace" the content of the link tag?

Comment: JS, innerHTML ...

Comment: which value you want to remove and no any button in your code..?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Took me 15 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, although it is kind of hacky. But then again: changing content through CSS is kind of hacky anyway. You can set the font-size of the actual link (`<a>`) to `0px`, and then "reset" the font-size for the pseudo elements.

```css
a{
  font-size: 0px;
}
a:before,
a:after{
  font-size: 16px;
}
a:before {
  content: 'ciao 1'
}

a:after {
  content: 'ciao 2'
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/">CSS Tutorial</a>
```

Comment: Rare to find accepted negatives.

Comment: @ManojKumar I think it is down-voted because even though this answer is a copy-pasted version of TemaniAfif's answer below, Temani's answer wasn't marked as the right one.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `font-size` trick like this:

```css
a {
  font-size: 0;
}

a:before {
  content: 'ciao 1';
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/">CSS Tutorial</a>
```

Or `visibility` like this:

```css
a {
  visibility: hidden;
}

a:before {
  content: 'ciao 1';
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/">CSS Tutorial</a>
```